# Convert Soap XML response to Object Java with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I have a response XML that I need to add in a Java object to use it, however this is null when I try to access something from it. 
I tried to make an unmarshal of it but without success

**The Body of XML received is this.**

> ```
>   <ns1:buscaCadastroImobiliarioGeralResponse>
>      <return xsi:type="ns1:retornoBuscaCadbciGeral">
>         <cadastros SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:cadastros[1]" xsi:type="ns1:listaCadastros">
>            <item xsi:type="ns1:cadastros">
>               <codigo_cadastro >xsi:type="xsd:string">461954</codigo_cadastro>
> ```

***The code that is executed***

```
BuscaCadastroImobiliarioGeral request = objectFactory.createBuscaCadastroImobiliarioGeral();

            Entrada entrada = new Entrada();
            entrada.setCodigoCadastro("461954");

            request.setEntrada(entrada);

            BuscaCadastroImobiliarioGeralResponse response = (BuscaCadastroImobiliarioGeralResponse) client.callWebService("url", request);

            System.out.println(response.getReturnResponse());

public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport{

    public Object callWebService(String url, Object request) {
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request);
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I get getReturnResponse it always comes null. Above is the classes of model

**CLASS BuscaCadastroImobiliarioGeralResponse**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "returnResponse"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "buscaCadastroImobiliarioGeralResponse")
public class BuscaCadastroImobiliarioGeralResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return", required = true)
    private ReturnResponse returnResponse;

    public ReturnResponse getReturnResponse() {
        return returnResponse;
    }

    public void setReturnResponse(ReturnResponse returnResponse) {
        this.returnResponse = returnResponse;
    }
}
```

**CLASS ReturnResponse**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "return", propOrder = {
    "cadastros"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "return")
@XmlSeeAlso(ReturnResponse.class)

public class ReturnResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<Cadastros> cadastros;


    public List<Cadastros> getCadastros() {
        return cadastros;
    }

    public void setCadastros(List<Cadastros> cadastros) {
        this.cadastros = cadastros;
    }
}
```

**CLASS Cadastros**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "cadastros", propOrder = {
    "item"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "cadastros")
@XmlSeeAlso(Cadastros.class)
public class Cadastros {

    @XmlElement
    private Item item;

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Problema relacionado: [Spring Web service unmarshalling not happening correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062306/spring-web-service-unmarshalling-not-happening-correctly)

Comment: Use the `wsdl` file to generate your Web Service types into `pojo` with `wsimport`. It should be easy to you after calling the service to get the result in the response `pojo`. https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Comment: I generate this, but the error continues